# Edit template exception in Blend 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, blend

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise version and when tried to edit template on blend, I got the following exception on design view. How can I get rid of it?

[image]

Comment: Does this happen on any control style template you open? Or just one's using the Toggle ButtonBase? You've got an issue in a VisualStateManager but would have to see your template(s) to find it.

Comment: No. This is happening to every template I am using in Blend. This comes soon when I click edit template for every control. So that I cant see the control and VSM in Edit state.

Comment: @Chris W. -Updated comment

Comment: I'd start looking at the ToggleButton base templates (ToggleButton, RadioButton, CheckBox, etc) and you're likely looking for a VisualState pointing to an object that doesn't actually exist in the Template it's in. This one of those one's that's really tough without sitting in front of it and it combing through stuff for a bit.